# Why was my question about the consequences of using Windows XP closed?

Tags: support, moderation, specific-question

I open this question on meta because I want to know why Anna Lear closed my [question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/110205/what-are-the-consequences-of-still-sticking-with-windows-xp-despite-there-are-win)? Is it my question really sucks or Anna Lear was angry with my comment in other unrelated [question](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2297/why-does-this-site-have-more-downvoted-closed-questions-than-other-stackexchange)?

Someone told me that I have offended the mod, so she just abuse her power to outright close my question without letting the community to decide. Is that true?

p/s: I don't know what is the correct tag for this question. So forgive me for the mistake.

Comment: eh, asking why also downvoted? If so, what is the purpose of meta?

Comment: Downvoting on meta [means something different](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/faq#vote-differences) than the main sites: not that you shouldn't have asked, but that the voter likely disagrees with the premise of the question.

Comment: Downvoters here are not mature and discourage people like me to participate on meta. Why asking *why* need to be downvoted? Jeff the owner where are you? Did you spot the problem? Is that a sin to question *why*? Is that a moderator is not questionable? I'm very upset and sad now.

Comment: @DeeJay I imagine people are disagreeing with your assertion that your question was closed for the wrong reason. Downvotes on meta are meant to convey disagreement, not discourage you from participating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just something to help you improve your question because I had almost considered sticking with XP because (until yesterday) I ran it from a VM out of linux. Now I've got win7.

One thing to ask is, how does having windows XP limit you as a programmer.

For me it was obvious - but not until I tried reinstalling Delphi XE2 for 64 bit compilation. But I didn't think of it at first and that's why this question ought to be improved and reopened.

Comment: please cast the open vote and edit my question

Comment: @dee I did, but you're going to have to edit it to get it reopened.

Comment: I have done that but I think it is hopeless to get it reopen.

Answer (score 7):

When a question is closed, it says exactly who closed the question and why it was closed. In this case, it says:

> #### closed as not constructive by Walter, Robert Harvey, TomWij, Anna Lear♦ yesterday
>
> This question does not meet enough of our [six guidelines for constructive subjective questions](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/). All questions should be practical, answerable, and of some educational value to the greater community. Chatty, open-ended discussion questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.

Three other people who are not Anna Lear voted to close the question because it's not constructive, and it has nothing to do with your earlier comment (although we are all curious and bemused by what you meant by that).

The question is too open-ended: you haven't provided any context to frame the question nor any specific problem that someone can help you solve. Answerers are forced to guess at what consequences they can dream up related to using Windows XP that may or may not be relevant to your circumstances.

Tell us *why* you're considering sticking with Windows XP. What programming problem do you have that's got you trying to hold onto the ghosts of Windows past? What specifically about Windows XP going the way of the dinosaurs has you concerned? Give us *something* about what you're trying to do to work with and provide an actual, correct answer.

Comment: oh i see, so anna is innocent

Answer (score 2):

Mark has covered the bases of why your question was considered not constructive by myself and 3 other community members, but I figured I'd come in and give you a definitive answer to the rest.

No, closing your question had nothing to do with your comment on meta. Two reasons:

1. To be honest, I didn't realize it was your question.
2. I was never angry at your meta comment. I'm still very curious to find out what you actually meant by it, but it never made me angry. I don't know who told you that you've offended a mod, but they were wrong.

In a hypothetical situation where I am angry or generally in a bad mood, I'm more likely to ask another moderator for a second opinion or take a break for a while until my mood improves.